# Spring Retry CompositeRetryPolicy is not working

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-retry

I'm using [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) module with the following RetryTemplate configuration:

```
@EnableRetry
@Configuration
public class RetryConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        final FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(500);

        final SimpleRetryPolicy attemptsPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        attemptsPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
        final TimeoutRetryPolicy timeoutPolicy = new TimeoutRetryPolicy();
        timeoutPolicy.setTimeout(2000);
        final CompositeRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new CompositeRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setPolicies(new RetryPolicy[] {timeoutPolicy, attemptsPolicy});

        final RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        return template;
    }
}
```

But the TimeoutRetryPolicy (used in CompositeRetryPolicy instance) is not working apparently.

I'm injecting RetryTemplate for consumption of SOAP services and in some cases it's taking more than 10 seconds to respond. However, through the configs I believe it should not take more than 4 seconds (2 seconds of timeout * 2 attempts).
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and unfortunately could not resolve using spring-retry. Therefore, I implemented my own generic class: **[RetryTemplate.java](https://gist.github.com/falvojr/4ddf12886df5d1471703682f98311da8)** (gist link).

Its use is very simple:

```
try {
    final int attempts = 2;
    final long timeout = 2000;
    final String foo = new RetryTemplate<String>(attempts, timeout).execute(() -> {
        // Your retryable logic here!
        return "Lorem ipsum";
    });
} catch (RetryException retryExpectedError) {
    // Your logic if the re-attempts is exceeded.
    // Note: RetryException is a simple inheritance of RuntimeException.
}
```

Although I have not implemented the control backoff, it would be trivial. I hope it helps!

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First the test-Service

```
@Service
public class RetrySoapServiceImpl implements RetryCallback<YourClass, YourException>{
    static private int i = 0;
        @Retryable(
        value = { YourException.class }, 
        maxAttempts = 300 //Just an Example. Try it with 6.
        @Override
        public PartnerWertelistenResponse doWithRetry(RetryContext arg0) throws YourException {
            System.out.println("Attempt "+i);
            i++;
            if (i<300) throw new YourException();
            else {
                System.out.println("No Exception");
                return null;
            }
        }       
}
```

Now the main code.

```
RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(5000); //You'll become mesages every 5 Seconds.
        TimeoutRetryPolicy policy = new TimeoutRetryPolicy();
        policy.setTimeout(50000L); //you'll be back in 50 Seconds, so you schould'nt wait 300*5 Sec.
        template.setRetryPolicy(policy); //It's the last point
        template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy); //It's the time to repeat an attempt

        try {
            YourClass result2 = template.execute(new RetrySoapServiceImpl());
        } catch (YourException e) {
            System.out.println("parent Catch Attempt "+e.getClass().getName());
        }
        System.out.println("ready to return");
```